# Laptop Harddisk not working

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, disk-utility

I have a Seagate hard disk (Laptop HD) which stopped working unexpectedly. I just Googled and tried a few things to get it to work but nothing seems to be happening.

I tried connecting the HD to my desktop using a SATA to USB adapater.  It detects the HD but I don't see it accessible in my computer. I see the drive is listed in Device Manger and in Disk Management utility. However, in Disk Management utility it says "Disk Not Ready" unable to initialize.

I removed the HD case and this is what I observed.

Opened the HD case. I see the head is moving while it is powered on, but just moves back to  the initial place (like idle) in few second after the disk spins for like 5 sec. However, the Disk rotates without any issues.

Is there any thing else I could try to get this working

Comment: Not once you've opened it. if it wasn't broken before, it is now.

Comment: i have closed the case and its the same like before drive is listed in Device Manger and also in Disk Management utility. However, in Disk Management utility it says "Disk Not Ready" unable to initialize.

Comment: The distance a drive head travels above the platen is measure in microns - smaller than any dust particle in the house. One particle hits the heads & it's bye bye heads. They are also in a bone-dry Nitrogen atmosphere. Your only chance now is probably a professional recovery service, or just grab the data off a backup & throw that one away.

Comment: Agree with @Tetsujin

Answer (score 0):

According to this article freezing the hard drive can help with recovery. 
http://lifehacker.com/5515337/save-a-failed-hard-drive-in-your-freezer-redux

It is also possible to request the services of a data recovery expert. Examine the terms and conditions, some companies charge for diagnosis.

Comment: This seems to be an attempt to reply to Tetsujin's comment, rather than an answer. (We allow only solutions in the answer section, generally.) Once you have sufficient reputation, you'll be able to comment everywhere.